# Average time difference of one column over condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe like this:

```
[{'Year': 2019, 'time_diff_new': 0, 'type1': 'Nan', 'Age': 861},
 {'Year': 2019, 'time_diff_new': 100, 'type1': 'Nan', 'Age': 861},
 {'Year': 2019, 'time_diff_new': 105, 'type1': 'Nan', 'Age': 861},
 {'Year': 2019, 'time_diff_new': 113, 'type1': 'Breaking', 'Age': 861},
 {'Year': 2019, 'time_diff_new': 127, 'type1': 'Breaking', 'Age': 861},
 {'Year': 2020, 'time_diff_new': 299, 'type1': 'Breaking', 'Age': 861},
 {'Year': 2020, 'time_diff_new': 462, 'type1': 'Nan', 'Age': 861},
 {'Year': 2021, 'time_diff_new': 601, 'type1': 'Breaking', 'Age': 861},
 {'Year': 2021, 'time_diff_new': 605, 'type1': 'Nan', 'Age': 861},
 {'Year': 2021, 'time_diff_new': 771, 'type1': 'Breaking', 'Age': 861},
 {'Year': 2021, 'time_diff_new': 855, 'type1': 'Nan', 'Age': 861},
 {'Year': 2021, 'time_diff_new': 861, 'type1': 'Nan', 'Age': 861}]
```

`time_diff_new` represents the days difference from the first date.

I want to calculate over `Age` column, I want to check how much time it takes in days for the next `breaking` change ( from `type1` column). But for `Age`, I want it to consider ranges, not just every value in `Age` individually.

Is there any way this could be achieved? I haven't done something like this before, so I am not sure where to start. Any suggestions or ideas would be highly appreciated.

Comment: I don't understand... From where is the value `182`? Can you [edit] your question and put there expected output?

Comment: I was giving that as an example that I wish to calculate over Age range, in how many days will `type1` column have a value=Breaking. I am not sure of the expected output as well

Comment: @BrieMerryWeather describe step by step. Based on what you provided, I can't figure out what is needed.

Comment: @inquirer, i am sorry it is a bit confusing for me as well. Let me try it a bit more clearly, what I want is the average time it takes for `type1= Breaking` to be appear. Like in approx how many days will the value be 'Breaking'. Now when this code is ran on the entire data, there are many age values. After which I need an aggregation that over Ages this to this, what is the average then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have mentioned in the comments that you yourself don't know what the expected output of your example DataFrame, it is very difficult to know whether what we might provide as a solution is what you are looking for.  From what I understand, you are looking to find the mean differences between `type1="Breaking"` for different `Age` ranges.

A couple of options for what you might be looking for:

```py
# only analysis on "Breaking"
df1 = df[df.type1.eq("Breaking")]
```

General grouping of ages, whether determined by yourself or not:

```py
# using pandas cut
groups = pd.cut(df1.Age, bins=3)
# or using numpy
import numpy as np
smallest = np.min(df1.Age)
largest = np.max(df1.Age)
num_edges = 3
groups = np.digitize(df1.Age, np.linspace(smallest, largest, num_edges))
# note that you could also use your own groups here, e.g.
# groups = np.digitize(df1.Age, [0, 20, 50, 100, 400, 600, 1000])

# ensure sorted
df1.sort_values("time_diff_new", inplace=True)
# group by groups and return mean difference between "Breaking"
df1.groupby(groups, as_index=True)["time_diff_new"].diff().mean()
# only 1 group returned here for sample data, as data has "Age"=861 for all columns
```

Or a function that returns the mean for a specified age range:

```py
def range_mean(df, min_age, max_age):
    # filter for values between ages only, and where type1 is "Breaking"
    df = df.loc[df.Age.between(min_age, max_age) & df.type1.eq("Breaking")]
    # ensure sorted
    df.sort_values("time_diff_new", inplace=True)
    # return the mean difference
    return df.time_diff_new.diff().mean()
    

range_mean(df, 860, 862)
# 164.5
```